# XML parser in java ; need to Parse unknow XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml

Can some guide me what is the best XML parser I can use in java? Similar to DOM as I have already checked the SAX it will not help me.
Also I **need to parse unknown XML** and save that content into file. So JAXB will not help me also.

Comment: Have you tried stax parser inbuilt in jdk. What you means by unknown XML ? How you are handling your XML tags?

Comment: What good is parsing going to do if you don't know what's in the XML? Please try to explain your task or problem in more detail.

Comment: Well the parsing part is easy; , the parser only requires valid XML, it does not care about the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Hi below class can help you parse and process the xml you receive .. jus add the imports and and replace the string with your xml..

```
 public class XML {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

            String xml = "<objects><student marks='one'/><student marks='two'/><school>Best school</school><teacher/></objects>";

            // parse the above xml
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"));
            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);

            // processing it 
            Node objects = doc.getDocumentElement();
            for (Node object = objects.getFirstChild(); object != null; object = object.getNextSibling()) {
                if (object instanceof Element) {
                    Element e = (Element)object;
                    if (e.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
                        String marks = e.getAttribute("marks");
                        System.out.println("It's a " + marks + " student!");
                    } else if (e.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("school")) {
                        String text = e.getTextContent();
                        System.out.println("It's a school that says \"" + text + "\".");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("I don't know what a " + e.getTagName() + " is for.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use the methods of Node like getFirstChild() and getNextSibling() to iterate through children. If you're parsing multiple documents, you can keep reusing the same DocumentBuilder